# Jquery abrir una casilla con Toggle y cerrar las demas casillas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo con `Jquery` dos botones, al hacer click se despliegauna de las dos funciones que están en el código de abajo.  Como puedo hacer para que al hacer clic en el boton `#lupa-responsive` se cierre el Boton `#apuntador-responsive` si estuviera abierto y viceversa.  Muchas gracias

```
function botonBuscarResponsive(){
 var contador = 0;
 $('#lupa-responsive').click(function(){
     $("#buscar-responsive").toggle("slow");
     $("#direccion-responsive").toggle("slow");
     if(contador == 0){
         $(".lupa-responsive").css({"background":"#90AA4D"});
         contador = 1;
     }else if(contador == 1){
         $(".lupa-responsive").css({"background":"#D8D8D8"});
         contador = 0;
     }
 });
}


function botonMapaResponsive(){
 var contador = 0;
 $('#apuntador-responsive').click(function(){
     $("#direccion-responsive").toggle("slow");
 });
}
```

---

HTML

```
 <div class="header-barra-blanca-responsive">
   <span  style="font-size:30px;" class="icon" id="favicon" style="color:#ffffff;">&#9776;</span>
   <div class="lupa-responsive" id="lupa-responsive"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/lupa.png"  alt="Buscar"/></div>
        <div class="header-direccion-responsive" id="apuntador-responsive"><img src="<?php echo get_home_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/location_icono.png"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="buscador center" id="buscar-responsive"><?php echo get_search_form(); ?></div>
   <div class="direccion-responsive" id="direccion-responsive"><span>AV Lorem ipsum Cll 13 96.</span> <a href="#">Ver mapa</a></div>
```

---

CSS

```
#buscar-responsive{
  display:none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #90AA4D;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}

#buscar-responsive .search-form input[type="search"]{
  background-color:#D8D8D8;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  font: 18px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
  color: #433f3f;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 6px 15px 6px 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
}
.header-barra-blanca-responsive{
    display:block
}
.lupa-responsive{
    background:#D8D8D8;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 39px;
    top: 7px;
}
.lupa-responsive img{
    width: 20px;
}
#direccion-responsive{
  display:none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #90AA4D; 
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}
#direccion-responsive a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D8D8D8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header-direccion-responsive{
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al final, lo que hace el método `toggle` es alternar el `display` del elemento entre `block` y `none`, si no me equivoco. La forma más rápida y con menos código sería utilizar los métodos de `show` y `hide`.

Lo que he entendido del código sin el html es que, al hacer click en `#lupa-responsive` debe mostrarse `#buscar-responsive` y ocultarse `#dirección-responsive` y al hacer click en `#apuntador-responsive` al revés.

```
$('#lupa-responsive').click(function(){
    $("#direccion-responsive").hide();
    $("#buscar-responsive").show();
});

$('#apuntador-responsive').click(function(){
     $("#buscar-responsive").hide();
     $("#direccion-responsive").show();
 });
```

Obviamente faltaría el resto de tu código.

Si lo he entendido mal, sería cambiar las funciones. `show()` mostrará el elemento y `hide()` lo ocultará, como sus nombres indican.

Comment: Muchas gracias.  Funciono perfectamente.